How to organize search in json file with the visualsearch.js?
I have the json file /data/items.json and javascript lib visualsearch.js. I need to search a data into the JSON file using this visualsearch.js. Someone can help me? Maybe someone can give me an example or demo?
I have text file in json format with data
[
 {
  "country": "USA",
  "state": "Texas",
  "city": "Houston",
  "link": "https://www.houston.us"
 },
 {
  ...
 }
]

...and JS
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
  <title>DocumentCloud's VisualSearch.js</title>
  <style>
 body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Avenir', sans-serif;
}

a {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #5B9FEF;
  color: #4A90E2;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.products {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.product-in-list {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.product-image a {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.product-header h2 {
  display: inline;
}

.product-header h2 a {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.product-details {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.product-details > * {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.product-categories {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.product-tags span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
  </style>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://documentcloud.github.io/visualsearch/build-min/visualsearch-datauri.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">

  <script src="https://documentcloud.github.io/visualsearch/build/dependencies.js"></script>
  <script src="https://documentcloud.github.io/visualsearch/build-min/visualsearch.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container" style="padding-left: 15px;padding-right: 15px;">

    <h1>Component Search</h1>

    <div class="visual_search"></div>

    <div id="content"></div>

    <pre id="result"></pre>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// here I get data fronm JSON
function fetchJSONData() {
    fetch('data.json')
        .then((res) => {
            if (!res.ok) {
                throw new Error
                    (`HTTP error! Status: ${res.status}`);
            }
            return res.json();
        })
        .then((data) => console.log(data))
        .catch((error) => console.error("Unable to fetch data:", error));
}
fetchJSONData();

// what to do next I do not know...

var visualSearch = null;
$(document).ready(function() {
    visualSearch = VS.init({
      container : $('#content'),
      query     : '',
      callbacks : {
        search  : function(query, searchCollection) {
          $('#result').html(query)
        },
        facetMatches : function(callback) {
          callback([
            'country', 'state', 'city'
          ]);
        },
        valueMatches : function(facet, searchTerm, callback) {
          switch (facet) {
            case 'country':
            callback([
                // I donot know hwat to do here
            ]);
            break;
          case 'state':
            callback([
                // I donot know hwat to do here
            ]);
            break;
          case 'city':
            callback([
                // I donot know hwat to do here
            ]);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });

</script>

</body>
</html>

Expected behavior
I need to make searching for several values and showing results

OR


The link to their documentation is outdated. Found the old link via Google: VisualSearch docs. It helps a lot if you post code and ideally a minimal reproducible example showing what you're trying to do and what you have trouble with.

Thanks @PeterPointer I added a minimal example ... that is all what I can...
